# How to use Django to resize a user's image and upload to Amazon S3?

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-s3

I am having trouble putting together two ideas, resizing an image from `models.ImageField` (which works fine if I don't try to also upload to my Amazon S3 bucket) and uploading an image to my Amazon S3 bucket).

My model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage as storage
import datetime
from PIL import Image
import math

class Artwork(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    # other fields...

    full_image_large = models.ImageField(storage=S3BotoStorage(location='img'))
    full_image = models.ImageField(storage=S3BotoStorage(location='img'), editable=False)
    thumbnail_image = models.ImageField(storage=S3BotoStorage(location='img'), editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self):
        super(Artwork, self).save()
        image = Image.open(self.full_image_large, 'r')
        (w, h) = image.size
        for width, target in zip([900.0, 350.0, 120.0], 
                                 [self.full_image_large,  
                                  self.full_image, 
                                  self.thumbnail_image]):
            r = width/w
            im = image.resize((int(math.floor(r*w)), 
                               int(math.floor(r*h))), 
                               Image.ANTIALIAS)
            im.save(target, format='JPEG')
```

So `full_image_large` is editable and it is the one that the user is able to upload. I want this photo, regardless of its size to be resized (keeping the aspect ratio) to be 900px in width. Then I am trying to also resize the same photo to `full_image` which should be 350px in width. Finally, I am trying to resize the same photo to `thumbnail_image` which should be 120px in width.

When I go to my site's admin url and save the object, I am getting the following error.

```
The 'full_image' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

The first image gets uploaded to Amazon S3 (if I comment out references to the two other images) just fine but nothing gets resized. If anyone can help me with the easiest way to accomplish what I am doing, that would be appreciated. Thanks. Note: I am using Python3.

I have also tried using `django-imagekit` without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following instead:

```
def save(self):
    image = Image.open(self.full_image_large)
    (w, h) = image.size
    r900 = 900.0/w
    im900 = image.resize((int(math.floor(r900*w)), int(math.floor(r900*h))), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    im900.save(self.full_image_large)

    r350 = 350.0/w
    im350 = image.resize((int(math.floor(r350*w)), int(math.floor(r350*h))), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    im350.save(self.full_image)

    r120 = 120.0/w
    im120 = image.resize((int(math.floor(r120*w)), int(math.floor(r120*h))), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    im120.save(self.thumbnail_image)

    super(Artwork, self).save()
```

You can do all three `resize` operations on the same `Image` instance - `image` in this case. Just save the results of that operation in a new object for each size, then save **that** object instead of saving the original `image` object.

However, one of Python's main tenets is DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself. The above code can be refactored like so:

```
def save(self):
    image = Image.open(self.full_image_large)
    (w, h) = image.size
    for width, target in zip([900.0, 350.0, 120.0], 
                             [self.full_image_large, 
                              self.full_image, 
                              self.thumbnail_image]):
        r = width/w
        im = image.resize((int(math.floor(r*w)), 
                           int(math.floor(r*h))), 
                           Image.ANTIALIAS)
        im.save(target)

    super(Artwork, self).save()
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) creates a tuple of each width and target.

Comment: Are you sure this would work with my storage using Amazon S3?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on the cleaner code. Unfortunately, the `save` function seems to not do anything. I edited my question to reflect the changes.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out how to use django imagekit to resize while keeping an aspect ratio.